# Incompatible types - found java.lang.String but expected int, in java

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

Displays the date 100 days from today, the day you were born, and the date 10,000 days after your birth date. I've done all that, but i want to take it a step further, i want the user to be able to input the number of days from today that he/she wishes to know the date of (if that makes any sense at all...). Here's what the part of the code i'm working on looks like:

```
 public class calendarProjectTest
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); //declare today's date
    GregorianCalendar myBirthday = new
    GregorianCalendar(1990, GregorianCalendar.JUNE, 9); //declare my birthday
    System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 0:");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String number = keyboard.next();
    int value = number;
    cal.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, number);
```

I'm using Bluej and it says, "incompatible types - found java.lang.String but expected int"
I'm at a loss. i don't have any idea what to do. any advise would be great. and yes, i know there are no end brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
cal.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(number));
```

As you can see from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29), the `add()` method needs both parameters as `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

problem lies here

```
String number = keyboard.next();
int value = number;
```

instead use :

```
int value = keyboard.nextInt(); // you will get parsed int value
cal.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard.next(); 
returns a string, not an integer.

so int value = number is trying to assign a string value to an int type. try putting this instead: **int value = Integer.parseInt( number );**

want more info about [GregorianCalendar](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/gregoriancalendar.html) and http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html